# I am getting this error in identitydbcontext in repository model design

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, repository-pattern, claims-based-identity

I get this error in the `IdentityDbContext` in the warehouse model design. I couldn't find anything in the Microsoft documentation. Can you help me? I'm using ASP.NET Core 8.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0311  The type 'Carebook.Dal.Concrete.EntityFramework.Conetext.AppDbContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'EfEntityRepositoryBase<TEntity, TContext>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Carebook.Dal.Concrete.EntityFramework.Conetext.AppDbContext' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityDbContext'.    Carebook.Dal    C:\Users\ASUS\Source\Repos\CarebookProject\Carebook.Dal\Concrete\EntityFramework\EfCareDal.cs   17  Active

[enter image de`enter code here`scription here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7puR.jpg)

What is the source of the error and how can I solve it?

```
  namespace Carebook.Dal.Concrete.EntityFramework
{
    public class EfCareDal: EfEntityRepositoryBase<Car,AppDbContext>,ICarDal
    {


    }
  public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int>
  {
      public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
      {

      }
      protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
      {
          builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
          base.OnModelCreating(builder);
      }

      public virtual DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
      public virtual DbSet<CarPicture> CarPictures { get; set; }
      public virtual DbSet<Feature> Features { get; set; }
      public virtual DbSet<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
      public virtual DbSet<Pricing> Pricings { get; set; }
      public virtual DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: The error states that AppDbContext must be a non abstract type, which means it is expecting a parameter that implements new()

Comment: Please don't post images of code, paste the actual text into your question.

Comment: Friends, I shared the codes, can you help me with the error?